# Measuring rectified voltage

Tags: diodes, rectifier, conversion

I am designing an analog circuit for motor control for that I need to rectify AC voltage using halfwave rectifier but I don't know how to calculate the rectified voltage in the given circuit below.

In simulation when I am measuring a voltage across R1 with DC voltmeter it shows 0V. But in web example, there is a formula for measuring a voltage Vdc=Vrmsx0.45 which is equal to 103.5V

Can you help and it will be helpful if the method is given for circuits like this
[image]

Comment: Google has lots of guidance.

Comment: Yes. But I am confused between simulation and web examples. That's why I came here!

Comment: Please show the difference between said simulation and web examples and we'll help.

Comment: So, be specific and explain what particularly confuses you about sim results and web examples. This site is a question and answer site and not a continuous learning resource.

Comment: Yup. In simulation When I am measuring a voltage across R1 with DC Voltmeter It shows 0V. But in web example, there is a formula for measuring a voltage Vdc=Vrmsx0.45 which is equal to 103.5V

Comment: Put this in your question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you RoyC